# Почему jQuery countTo timer показывает только 100?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, count, счетчики

Всем привет! Подключаю плагин:
https://github.com/mhuggins/jquery-countTo/blob/master/readme.md

в тему wordpress, но какое бы значение я не вводил , на котором счетчику нужно остановится - он всегда стопорится на отметке 100. Подключаю на простую страницу html - работает норм. Почему так может быть?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите внимательно документацию, там написано, что по умолчанию счет идет лишь до 100, чтобы увеличить этот предел, необходимо передать новое значение либо при инициализации таймера средствами JavaScript, либо с помощью атрибута `data-to` HTML-элемента.

Comment: Да, спасибо, смотрел. Читайте мой пост внимательнее: я же уже говорил, что на тестовой html страничке у меня все получается задавать с помощью параметров data-to и data-from как в большую, так и меньшую сторону, но как только переношу все в тему wordpress - при любых значениях останавливается только на 100

Comment: Возможно, шаблонизатор WP отрезает все лишние атрибуты. Посмотрите исходник страницы, выдаваемой WP, все ли там на месте.

Comment: да нет, все на месте:
<h3 class="timer count" data-from="0" data-to="52"></h3>